# Drawcall Batching with Ambient Occlusion

Tags: unity, ambient-occlusion

I'm creating a low poly 4X game that will likely have upwards of 200 unique hex tile models once everything is said and done. The colour palette consists of 16 different colours. I understand that if I want to reduce the number of draw calls I could simply UV map each individual model to the palette and there wouldn't be a problem.

However, I want to add an ambient occlusion effect which is best achieved by baking it on in Blender. This precludes me from using a single material for all my models since each model will have a different pattern baked onto the palette. I'm going to go out on a limb and say that having a different material for each model could create a pretty severe CPU bottleneck.

So, what would my best solution be? Should I abandon AO altogether? Perhaps I should try lightmapping in Unity (though I've heard AO baking in modelling software yields better effects)?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're not limited to a single UV channel per mesh. You could use one UV channel to look up into the palette, and a second UV channel for your ambient occlusion texture (atlas). Or you could store the palette colour as a vertex colour channel. MaterialPropertyBlocks might help too, since they're meant to be lighter weight than full material changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Unity's AO when baking. Should be working fine in general.

If it's a high end game then you may also use SSAO which is runtime. There is a cheap [SSAO Pro](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/22369) package in Unity Asset Store too.

Comment: Also the quite new Unity Post Processing Stack supports ambient occlusion. It is free.